# Trigger blur event on an array of input elements

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName" class="control-label">* First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control validate validate-required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName" class="control-label">* Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control validate validate-required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">* Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control validate validate-required">
</div>
```

I'm validating a form, and for any error, I push the *name* (string) of the input into an errors array. When I'm done validating, I have this script:

**JavaScript:**

```
if (that.errors.length > 0)
{
    $.each(that.errors, function(key, element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.trigger('blur');
    });
}
```

I need to trigger a blur event on every input that is in this array. I am able to get only one element to work. For example, each element should get a red border.

If I console log out each element, the system is seeing them, but my UI just isn't reflecting it.

```
[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "firstName", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function…]
[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "lastName", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function…]
[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "email", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function…]
```

The `that.errors` is just a list of input names (string values). For example:

```
[0] - firstName
[1] - lastName
[2] - email
```

**EDIT**

I have posted the related markup.
When I manually give an element focus, then tab out (blur) the input is validated. I am getting a red border if the input is invalid.

However, if I use the above method to trigger a blur, the system is seeing every input correctly, it seems like the blur() event isn't getting triggered correctly. I'm not able to get a red border on any of the inputs in the errors array.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you please post the related markup?

Comment: I just noticed this works: `$('#' + element).trigger('blur');` I get red borders around all of my inputs. Can someone explain why that is? I thought I had a jQuery object by using `var $element = $(element);`

Comment: `$('#lastName')` searches for the element with `id=lastName`, `$('lastName')` tries to locate element with tag `<lastName>`.

Comment: From what I can see, it would be due to the fact that the errors array does not contain a live reference to a HTML object, it contains the name of the field. What you're doing in your above comment is asking jQuery to fetch it based on ID. Your code above $(element) expects element to be an object reference to a DOM object.

Comment: it depends on what `that.errors` is

Comment: Now that I see it written out as `id=lastName, $('lastName')` that makes perfect sense. Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: So now you can take the chance to clearly state what you push into the array in the first paragraph. Goes a long way.

Comment: It never occurred to me that I was only grabbing the name of the element until you brought it up. So obvious now! :)

Comment: If you only have the name available, you could do `$('input[name=' + element + ']').trigger('blur');` instead of `var $element = $(element); $element.trigger('blur');`